# How does django admin resolves models from url?

Tags: django

How does django-admin resolves model from url?

I takes url like this "/admin/video/item/"

How can I do the same? Get model from that url...

I need to implement function which gets '/admin/vide/item' and returns Item object in video app.

Update:

I can easily turn 'admin/video/items' to video.models.Item but im not sure if first later in model name is uppercase or there can be more uppercase laters.

Documentation says:

```
view, args, kwargs = urlresolvers.resolve('/admin/video/item/')
enter code hereview(*args,**kwargs)
```

so i have view right? The next question how do i get model from that view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin urls consist of the app label and the model name.

You can use `django.db.models.get_model` to get a model class from those two strings.

```
# urls
(r'^admin/(?P<app_label>\w+)/(?P<model_name>\w+)/$', my_view),

# view
from django.db.models import get_model

def my_view(request, app_label, model_name):
    model_class = get_model(app_label, model_name)
    return http.HttpResponse(model_class.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file applications structure registered in the admin. I mean, wen you register a model, the first element to be indexed is the application name, and the second is the model name defined in the models.py. so this means that it will search the item class defined in video/models.py.

By the settings file you can import into your view the absolute path of your project and then dynamically import the required model using split over the request.path and... at the end get the item with the id, wich is the last item in your splited string.

Comment: its dirty. and and does not help me if the model name has more than one uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Yuji's answer, assuming you are building this for 'non-staff' users, here is the GCBV way to do the same thing:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^(?P<app_label>[\w\-]+)/(?P<model_name>[\w\-]+)/$', DynamicListView.as_view(), name='list'),


# views.py    
class DynamicListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
      template_name = 'dynamic_list.html'

      @property
      def model(self):
        return apps.get_model(app_label=str(self.kwargs['app_label']), model_name=str(self.kwargs['model_name']))

      @property
      def app_label(self):
        return str(self.kwargs['app_label'])

      def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(DynamicListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(**self.request.GET.dict())

      def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return super(DynamicListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

        else:
            # Set permissions here for non-staff users
```

I posted a question similar to this here: [Dynamically pass app_label and model_name to the url in Python Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342813/dynamically-pass-app-label-and-model-name-to-the-url-in-python-django)