# Dynamically pass app_label and model_name to the url in Python Django

Tags: python, django, crud, dry

I'm curious, why aren't more people talking about code consolidation by dynamically passing app_label and model_name as arguments to the URL.

In building generic CRUD actions for 'non-staff' users I've been searching for the most 'DRY' method. I started out trying to extend the Django Admin for 'non-staff' users. Later I came across Django-Generic-Scaffold, which is awesome, but scaffolds models up front rather than dynamically on-demand.

After digging through the Django Admin source code I discovered this technique and have it working well but I wonder why is this technique isn't discussed more?

## urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<app_label>[\w\-]+)/(?P<model_name>[\w\-]+)/$', DynamicListView.as_view(), name='list'),
```

## views.py

```
class DynamicListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
  template_name = 'dynamic_list.html'

  @property
  def model(self):
    return apps.get_model(app_label=str(self.kwargs['app_label']), model_name=str(self.kwargs['model_name']))

  @property
  def app_label(self):
    return str(self.kwargs['app_label'])

  def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(DynamicListView, self).get_queryset()
    if self.app_label == 'auth':
        return Http404
    else:
        return queryset.filter(**self.request.GET.dict())

  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return super(DynamicListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    else:
        # Set permissions here for non-staff users
```

For example, let's say we have an app called 'Library' and two models Book and Author:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

  def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

With this technique we could use a single set of URLs to list, create, update Book, Author or any other model:

http://domain/library/book/
or 
http://domain/library/author/

I develop apps that have over 50 models in a project. In the past I "hard coded" views for each model but its so repetitive. To the Django folks out there, is this a commonly used technique or are there issues with solving problems this way?

Comment: You have to be careful with this pattern. Your current setup allows users to see/change _all_ models, even "internal" models such as `Permission` or `Site`. The admin explicitly white-lists apps/models that are registered by generating an url pattern of the form `(?P<app_label>app_1|app_2|app_3)`. In my experience, different models often have slightly different requirements. This may be different in your case, but I suspect it's true for most websites. These small differences greatly limit the usefulness of this pattern.

Comment: Just what knbk says: simple generic CRUD rarely fit the real domain's complexity (and that's one of the limitations of the "admin" app too FWIW). I have been doing django projects for more than 10 years now and never had a case where a generic CRUD was of any use. But if it solves your problem then that's fine...

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I use dispatch to manage the app_label whitelist which I didn't include in the above code. Also, about 90% of what my non-staff users do is basic crud actions. I hope this helps.